# How do I disable the window-switching effect of mouse-roll in Debian 8.1 (KDE)?

Tags: debian, scrolling, plasma

I have installed **Debian 8.1**.

It originally ran *LXDE* but I then installed KDE Plasma 4 on it (which is the desktop environment I am currently using)

Now whenever I roll the centre mouse button back and forward (roller) it causes my windows to switch

#### Example:

I have Google Chrome open at the moment,

- if I roll forward my Nautilus window opens,
- if I roll forward further my terminator window opens.

I find this very irritating as sometimes I want to be able to scroll down on pages quickly and I usually use my mouse roller to do this.